# How create an encrypted mounted Folder

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, driver, directory

I want to create a mounted Folder to be encrypted later, my point is that create a normal directory(`C:\path\to\myfolder`) and mount it to a drive (`I:\`) so any change will occurs in both path, my goal is if any file  added to `I:\` will be automatically encrypted in `C:\path\to\myfolder`

Questions:

- How to monitor the mounted folder and encrypt its children (files or directories) without touching files or directories under the drive.
- is there any way to create this mounted folder from the beginning so any file added will be automatically encrypted under the folder and decrypted under the drive, and if it is already exist when I mount it, files will be decrypted under the associated drive.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should the file appear encrypted in `C:\path\to\myfolder` and unencrypted in `I:\` ? What's the point?

Comment: my point is if I want to mount `C:\path\to\myfolder` to a drive just unencrypt files and directories under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use NTFS encryption then you can make use of [`EncryptFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API that will make existing file/directory encrypted. If directory is provided any new files added to it will be encrypted.

More information at [Handling Encrypted Files and Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365005%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Or do you want to implement your own encryption driver?

Comment: Yes @Rohan, `EncryptFile` don't let me choose the encryption algorithm that is already implemented in my application, any ideas please !!!!

Comment: @oumaya, In that case I think you would have to implement file system minifilter driver to encrypt file data. Little more complicated!

Comment: So I should create my own file system driver that what you mean? and how about Dokan library it doesn't help?

Comment: You would need _file system filter driver_ (more preferred now is minifilter driver). I don't know much about Dokan library.

Comment: I am pressed by time, so I will use EncryptFile right now and I will try with minifilter driver later, thank you for your precious idea @Rohan :)

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, there is a utility called encfs (encrypted filesystem) that allows to have an encrypted folder and mount a decrpyted version of the folder in some other folder.

There is a windows port available (http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html), but I have never used it.

Note that this solution is in the OS itself, but you should be able to access both folders programmatically if desired, and probably also mount/unmount the folders using system call from your application.

Comment: thank you @Zane it is really interesting, but my application create an ordinary folder mount it to a chosen drive and can dismount it, the only feature last to do is to encrypt any file created within the drive under the created folder (the encryption algorithm is implemented too)